# How to save resources when repeating options of a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, foreach

I am creating a relation about 50 people and set their role in just one page (a business requirement).

- People is a free text field,
- though role contains about 100 entries.

Eventually the page is taking a long time to load.
I want to make it load faster.

So, my PHP code is easy. However, to load the page it takes a long time, as each of the 50 people has one `<select ...><option></option>**100times**</select>.`

```
<?php
for($p = 0 $p<50, $p++){
  echo "<select ...>";
    foreach ($option as $i=>$value){
      echo "<option value=$i>$value</option>";
          /*** Eventually the HTML of this is huuuuuuge ****/
    }
}
```

I would like to have some trick in the HTML that allows me to:

```
<list name=repeatedList><values></values></list>
<select><use list=repeatedlist></select>
```

or even a jQuery that transfers the responsibility of generating that 100 options to the browser , instead of having to transfer these 100 options 50 times to the user.

Comment: I guess you want to have some autocompletion list with limited amount of possible options to choose from. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @Xesenix , in fact, it really goes very close to what I want, though users should know the first letter first.
Is there any way to     
`$( "#tags" ).onLoad({
      source: availableTags
    });`

Comment: i have added anwser with something that should initialize autocomplete for empty strings not sure if there is something that can block it from sending request on empty term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render the dropdown once in the backend then use jQuery to copy the dropdown to all Person rows. Consider the following example:

```js
$(function() {
  var template = $('#roleTemplate').html();
  $('td.role').html(template);
});
```

```css
#roleTemplate {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Render the Role template once in PHP -->
<div id="roleTemplate">
  <select name="role[]">
    <option>Role 1</option>
    <option>Role 2</option>
    <option>...</option>
    <option>Role 100</option>
  </select>
</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Person</th>
    <th>Role</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type=text name=person[]></td>
    <td class="role"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type=text name=person[]></td>
    <td class="role"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type=text name=person[]></td>
    <td class="role"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type=text name=person[]></td>
    <td class="role"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type=text name=person[]></td>
    <td class="role"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type=text name=person[]></td>
    <td class="role"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Since you have more than 100 options in the dropdown I also recommend looking into a plugin like [Select2](https://select2.org/) which offers search functionality and multiple data source types including an ajax source and a static array. Consider the following example which uses a static array as the source for all dropdowns, the source can be generated once in PHP.

```js
$(function() {
  $('select.role').select2({
    data: RoleList,
    width: 200
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/select2@4.0.7/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/select2@4.0.7/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script>
  // Generate the Role list in PHP, can be printed with json_encode(array)
  var RoleList = [{
      id: 1,
      text: 'Role 1'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Role 2'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: 'Role 3'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      text: 'Role 4'
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      text: 'Role 5'
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      text: 'Role 6'
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      text: 'Role 7'
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      text: 'Role 8'
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      text: 'Role 9'
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      text: 'Role 10'
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      text: 'Role 11'
    },
  ]
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Person</th>
    <th>Role</th>
  </tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="person[]"></td><td><select class="role"></select></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="person[]"></td><td><select class="role"></select></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="person[]"></td><td><select class="role"></select></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="person[]"></td><td><select class="role"></select></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="person[]"></td><td><select class="role"></select></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="person[]"></td><td><select class="role"></select></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="person[]"></td><td><select class="role"></select></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="person[]"></td><td><select class="role"></select></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="person[]"></td><td><select class="role"></select></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="person[]"></td><td><select class="role"></select></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="person[]"></td><td><select class="role"></select></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="person[]"></td><td><select class="role"></select></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="person[]"></td><td><select class="role"></select></td></tr>
  
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If [JQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete) is something that you can use and only problem is showing some default result for empty string you probably can do something like this:

```
// initialize cache when rendering website on server side i assume php
var globalAutocompleteCache = {
  '': <?php echo json_encode($options) ?>
};
```

this may be in separate file with other js stuff

```
// initialize inputs with autocomplete
$('#tags').autocomplete({
  // ... other configuration
  // this will turn on caching
  source: (request, response) => {
    var term = request.term;
    if (term in globalAutocompleteCache) { // as empty should be initialized it will return immediatly
      response(globalAutocompleteCache[term]);
    } else {
      // some ajax request 
      $.getJSON("more_data.php", request, function(data, status, xhr) {
        cache[term] = data;
        response(data);
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Not tested but something like that should work.